# Determining backpropagation accuracy is good or not

Tags: neural-network, classification, backpropagation

I'm doing research on classification using backpropagation and getting 86% accuracy . How to determining whether this is good or not? Are there journal references about the accuracy range? thank you

Comment: 86% accuracy on what dataset?

Comment: On characters image classification

Comment: Find the source of you dataset and look it up in https://arxiv.org/ .